# Loading a file from Mega.nz to utilise in java project

Tags: java, file, oop, caching, path

Is it possible to load a file from my mega.nz account to use in my java project?

I have a big cache to read from and I don't want it to be placed in my project file and would like to read it from an external place. I also don't want it on my desktop or anything like that.

At the moment I have:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("contentFolder/cache/"); //gets the cache from the content folder
    }

}
```

I don't know how to get files outside of the project without adding them to the build path, so is it even possible to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody build a Java API, but it is not maintained any more for 3 years, see https://github.com/Ale46/Mega-Java. The Android application (in Java) uses the C++ directly.

If you don't want to combine the C++ SDK with Java but have a native Java program, you probably need to do some programming and do HTTP requests yourself. The bash script "megadown" could be a good starting point how to do it: https://github.com/tonikelope/megadown/blob/master/megadown

Anyhow, I recommend using a service that has a standard API which makes that easier. For example, a lot of file services provide an S3 API.

Comment: Is it not possible with pure java? Like how you can use URL and Scanner to read text files form online repositories?